# RuboCop: Different parameters for different directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I'm wondering if there are a way of specifying different parameters for different directories.

For instance, I would like RuboCop to be more gentle with my tests. Is there a way to re-write this setup?

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 20
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'

Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 30
  Include:
    - 'spec/**/*'
```

Right now I'm getting `.rubocop.yml:X: 'Metrics/AbcSize' is concealed by line Y`

Update:

Ended up with two `.rubocop.yml` files:

`[project-root]/.rubocop.yml`:

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 20
```

`[project-root]/spec/.rubocop.yml`:

```
inherit_from: ../.rubocop.yml

Metrics/AbcSize:
  Max: 30
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create separate `.rubocop.yml` in `/spec` with desired rules. Rubocop will pick it up

> RuboCop will start looking for the configuration file in the directory
>   where the inspected file is and continue its way up to the root
>   directory.

Ref https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I will update my post with the final solution to my problem. Unfortunately I cannot upvote you due to low reputation.